# Having trouble with my contact form

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I'm having a little trouble with my contact form. It's sending emails to my server but somehow it's not taking the information from the `"email"` field. Instead, what I get in the `"From:"` field is my address on the server like this: `"muzedima@box693.bluehost.com"`.It's not taking the info from the "name" field either. What did I do wrong? Also, I'm trying to get the subject line to say the name of the sender, but I failed miserably, is it possible?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="large-7 medium-10 small-12 medium-centered large-centered column">
        <div class="row">
            <form method="post" action="email2.php">

                    <input type="text" name="name" class="defaultText" title="your name">
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="defaultText" title="your email address">


                    <textarea name="comments1" class="defaultText" title="Tell us about your business"></textarea>
                    <textarea name="comments2" class="defaultText" title="How can we help?"></textarea>


               <div class="large-7 medium-10 small-12 medium-centered large-centered column">
                    <input type="submit" name="send message" value="Send Message">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the PHP script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
$to      = 'info@muzedimage.com';
$name    = $_POST['name'] ; 
$email   = $_POST['email'] ;
$subject = 'Inquiry from $name'; 
$comments1 = $_POST['comments1'] ;
$comments2 = $_POST['comments2'] ; 
$message = $comments1 .  "\n\n" . $comments2;
$headers = "From: $name,  $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.muzedimage.com'</script>";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out,
  {
  echo "Oops!, you forgot your email!";

  }
?>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP variables are not evaluated inside of single quotes, only double quotes, therefore change the following:

```
$subject = 'Inquiry from $name'; 
//to
$subject = "Inquiry from $name";
```

Also for the email portion, you're not doing anything with it... so do something with it.

```
$message = $comments1 .  "\n\n" . $comments2 . "\n\n" . $email;
```

Now it sends the email as well.

Comment: Thank you! this partially solved my problem. However the problem remains: In the email I receive, the from section does not have the email of the sender but instead my server side email. How do i fix that?

Comment: can you explain to me why adding the email in the message portion of the code enable it to work? I dont get it.

Comment: @user3213485 It worked fine before. Adding it to the `message` enables it to come through the body of the message. `variable instantiation` alone doesn't do anything.

Comment: Also I just tested the page without enter any email address and the message:"oops you forgot your email" didnt appear. How do I get it to appear?

Comment: @user3213485 My friend, it is time for you to learn to develop in PHP. These are all questions easily answered by a little digging and learning. I'm sorry but I won't be able to help any further in this case.

Comment: It was a "joint effort". All is well @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0):

`Ohgodwhy` already pointed out one of the issues with your code, so I won't bother repeating it.

In regards as to why you're receiving the `From:` as `"muzedima@box693.bluehost.com"` is because of this line:

```
$headers = "From: $name,  $email";
```

It needs to be like this:

```
$headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
```

The `$email` variable must be encapsulated by `<` and `>` and it's best to end it with `\r\n`

Tested and working with both `Ohgodwhy's` answer and mine.